# Overwrite last line outputted to std::cout in a stream-like fashion

Tags: c++, c++11, ostream, streambuf

Hi,

Here is what I am trying to achieve. I would like to have a stream, defaulting to outputting to `std::cout` but that could work with `std::cerr` too, that allows overwriting the last outputted line.

I am aware this will not work with seekp because std::cout is not seekable. The way I circumvent this is by instead outputting `'\b'` characters. I also know this solution does not allow to go back one line up and that's fine.

I managed to [get a solution](http://ideone.com/1MJPkV) but it is not nice (by the way, the version given in the link works with the real console even though it does not work with ideone - ideone shows `\b` as a blank character). I would like an interface like the standard streams. Something like:

```c++
Logger log(std::cerr);
log << "hello" << 1 << erase << "hi" << std::endl;
```

This should output `"hello1\b\b\b\b\b\bhi"` on `std::cerr` and the user will only see `"hi"`.

I managed to get [something close](http://ideone.com/wNcXS9) by inheriting `std::ostream` and `std::streambuf` but it does not compile (see link).

What would be a solution to this problem?
Please note that I am not particularly attached to my solution. Any solution letting me achieve the "stream way" is okay.

Comment: Code in links is considered non existing on Stack Overflow. Provide a [MCVE] that reproduces the error.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ sorry about that. The minimal example is still quite long, is it okay to copy-paste it then?

Comment: No, I said minimize to reproduce the compiler error.

Comment: @ibizaman If it is quite long, it is probably not minimal. Did you really cut out every part that is not essential to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: I understand, I'll try my best. Please leave me some time.

Comment: BTW, implementing a `std::streambuf` interface should be sufficient. You shouldn't need to inherit `std::ostream`. @ibizaman

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with this task?